# Should Agile user stories always be from the end-user's perspective?

Tags: agile, user-stories

In Agile, should the 'user' in a user story always be the end-user or could it refer to different type of user? For example, is it acceptable to write something along the lines of, "As a developer I would like to have an interface to component B so that I can communicate with it from component A" or should it be restructured in terms of the benefit that such an interface would ultimately present to the end-user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris,

The answer is "it depends on who the customer is". User stories need to be understandable and if possible written by your customer. If your customer is a developer of component A or B then it would make sense to you both.

However, if the customer doesn't immediately see the benefit of that I would ask "why" I was adding that interface and keep asking "why" until I get to an answer that the customer does understand. Then I'd write the user story so that the customer can understand what is being delivered.

Mike Cohen's book User Stories Applied is very good if you're looking for something more substantial to read.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/User-Stories-Applied-Development-Signature/dp/0321205685/ref=cm_rdp_product

Comment: Thanks for your answer and book recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. If you are say writing a dll to develop with, then you are the end user of the dll...